# What happens to the motion of the body if acceleration equal zero?

Tags: kinematics, acceleration, velocity

$If$ the body moves with $variable$ velocity and $variable$ acceleration ,but at a certain instant the $acceleration$ was zero then we can say at this instant the body moves with constant $velocity$ $??
$
Example:
let Velocity=$(t^2)$-$2t$,  acceleration=$2t$-$2$, then at $t=1$,the acceleration equal zero then at $(t=1)$ the body moves with constant velocity ??

Comment: You don't seem to have the proper units for velocity and acceleration.

Comment: If you call an instant, where the velocity does not change as "constant " velocity, its ok. but than if you walk you have at every step the way constant etc, to speak of a constantly changing velocity in an instant  where this change ist 0 does not make much sense .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Example:
> let Velocity=(t^2)-2t,  acceleration=2t-2, then at t=2,the acceleration equal zero then at (t=2) the body moves with constant velocity ??

First of all, the acceleration:
$$
a = 2t - 2
$$
is **not** zero at $t=2$. The acceleration is zero at $t=1$.

---

At $t=1$ the velocity is:
$$
v(1) = -1
$$

The fact that the acceleration is zero at $t=1$ means that, for small $\delta t$ the velocity at time $1 + \delta t$ is unchanged except for terms of order higher than linear in $\delta t$:
$$
v(1+\delta t) = -1 + O(\delta t^2)
$$

This is because, generally:
$$
v(t + \delta t)  = v(t) + a(t)\delta t + O(\delta t^2)
$$

---

You would typically *not* say that "the body moves with constant velocity," since this typically does not refer to a single point in time, but to a range of times.

Typically, one says that the velocity is constant if, for a range of times:
$$
\frac{dv}{dt} = 0\;,
$$
but here, we only have $\frac{dv}{dt}=0$ at a single instant, so we would not usually call this "constant velocity."

We would just say that the instantaneous acceleration is zero at the time $t=1$. We don't need to say anything else than that.

Comment: but even if for small time interval the velocity will change and the acceleration will also change

Comment: Yes, that's also true. So what?

Comment: oh I got what you are saying 
we say the body moves only with constant velocity for range of times but not for single instant in time

Comment: Yes,  correct, that is what we typically say. (Probably because it would be confusing to say the velocity is "instantaneously constant" so instead we can say that "the instantaneous acceleration is zero").